# Phantomjs disable javascript in page but enable included javascript

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to retrieve CSS information from a page without execute its javascript. For example here is the code snippet.

```
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = false;
page.open('file:///home/sample.html', function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        page.includeJs("file:///home/sample.js", function() {
            var class = page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.querySelector('body').className;
            });
            console.log(class);
        });
    }
}
```

If I disabled the javascript, the evaluate function always return null. But when I tried to enable the javascript, the evaluate function will return some value. Is there any idea to disable the javascript in the page, but my included javascript have to work ?

Comment: What do you mean by your last sentence? You want to run some javascript but not all?

Comment: @WhatisSober the page I opened contains javascript code. I don't want that code to be executed. But then I include some script to help me to retrieve the information I want. So i need my included javascript from phantomjs to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

`page.evaluate()` executes JavaScript on the page. If you disable JavaScript in PhantomJS, then you effectively can't use `page.evaluate()` anymore. And with it goes every way of accessing DOM elements. `page.includeJs()` will also not work, because it the script cannot be executed on the page.

You can still access `page.content` which provides access to the current page source (computed source). You may try to use some DOM library to parse the source into a DOM object<sup>1</sup> or if the task is simple, you may try to use Regular Expressions.

<sup>1</sup> Note that PhantomJS and node.js have different execution environments, so most node.js modules that deal with the DOM won't work

Comment: What about removing all `<script>` tags from the document before either has been loaded. Is that possible? That would effectively disable JavaScript.

Comment: @Gajus If a script tag is in the DOM then it is most likely already executed. There is a very short window where the initial `<script>` is delivered to the browser and the remaining content of the script is still in transit. This is true for script elements directly contain JavaScript. If a script element has a `src` attribute, then an additional JavaScript file will be downloaded, which you can [`abort()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html), but it will be tricky. I wouldn't say that it disables JavaScript. It's just preventing it to be executed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have added an answer suggesting to use HTTP proxy to achieve the above. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41893648/368691

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by Artjom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30693757/368691), there is no way to disable execution of the target website JavaScript without disabling PhantomJS ability to execute JavaScript on the page. However, there is a simple way to ensure that no scripts are executed by the target website (which achieves the same result, at the end).

1. Create a HTTP proxy that intercepts all requests.
2. Detect responses with `Content-Type: text/html`.
3. Remove all `<script>` tags from the document.

You can configure [phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs) to use proxy using [`--proxy` configuration](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html).

Use [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) to create a proxy server.

Use `cheerio` to remove, comment out, or otherwise invalidate the `<script>` tags.